# Poder seleccionar fecha a partir del día siguiente al actual en mi campo de fecha

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

tengo un formulario y en el campo desplegable de fecha, necesito que solo se pueda elegir el día siguiente al actual en el que se está llenando el formulario.

Aquí el código

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" 
    integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <div class="item">
          <p>Fecha de envío</p>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha" required/>
          <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </div>
```

Comment: Solo agrega el atributo `min` con la fecha mínima: `min="2020-06-26"`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero por ejemplo si hoy lleno el formulario, no me  debe permitir elegir el 26 de junio, si lo lleno mañana no me debe permitir elegir el 27 de junio etc...

Comment: Sólo haz algo como `<input type="date" id="fechaMin" />` y un script `fechaMin.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];`

Comment: Ayudaría mucho una respuesta publicada @JheymanMejia

Comment: @LuciaCu, ayudaría saber qué lenguaje de servidor usas para poder sugerirte cómo agregar siempre la fecha actual, o usar la opción que te acaban de sugerir para hacerlo directamente con javascript.

Comment: @Triby creo que hacerlo en javascript es la opción, pero necesito poder poner la fecha siguiente a la actual, no la actual en sí. Que esté bloqueada la fecha de hoy y la fecha minima sea mañana.

Comment: Trata de seguir la sugerencia de @JheymanMejia mientras esperamos a ver si lo publica como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

como te comentaron ese agregar el atributo min, como va cambiando cada día entonces es necesario un script como el siguiente.

Puede ser mas compacto pero lo deje asi para que veas que sucede por pasos:

```
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

const minValue = tomorrow.toISOString().split("T")[0];

document.getElementById('fecha').min = minValue;
```

Si quieres la forma resumida seria:

```
const minValue = new Date();
minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate() + 1);
document.getElementById('fecha').min = minValue.toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

Aquí dejo el ejemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/elporfirio/y9v0rcxu/

Comment: Convendría explicarás el javascript

Comment: Aparte de la explicación, también sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo verificable aquí mismo usando _Fragmento de código_

Comment: Quedó resuelto, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @LuciaCu, si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: @BetaM son funciones primitivas de JavaScript, como no generé nada nuevo no tiene mayor explicación que buscar los métodos en JS

Comment: Hay usuarios novatos que desconocen las _funciones primitivas de Javascript_ y, precisamente, por eso preguntan.